# GraphQL query the same collection

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I have a filtered query in GraphQL that return only some specific content , while I want to add this same query but to display all it content . I cannot use two similar queries in the same page , eventually I cannot pass this all data that I want , even if I add this query in a component it will cause an error of undefined .
This is the query :

```
  allPrismicCollection(
    sort: {fields: data___collection___text, order: ASC}
    limit: $limit
    skip: $skip
  ) {

    nodes {
      data {
        slides {
          slide {
            document {
              ... on PrismicSlide {
                data {
                  blogs {
                    blog {
                      document {
                        ... on PrismicBlog {
                          uid
                          data {
                            image {
                              gatsbyImageData(aspectRatio: 1.5)
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and this is the query I want to add as well :

```
  allPrismicCollection {
    nodes {
      data {
          collection {
          text
        }
        slides {
          slide {
            document {
              ... on PrismicSlide {
                id
                data {
                  blogs {
                    blog {
                      document {
                        ... on PrismicBlog {
                          id
                          data {
                            tags {
                              tag
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      
      }
    }
  }
```

Any idea how to mix these queries , or maybe to add it independently in components ?!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot use two similar queries in the same page

You can as long as you alias them. Like:

```
  result1: allPrismicCollection(
    sort: {fields: data___collection___text, order: ASC}
    limit: $limit
    skip: $skip
  ) {

    nodes {
      data {
        slides {
          slide {
            document {
              ... on PrismicSlide {
                data {
                  blogs {
                    blog {
                      document {
                        ... on PrismicBlog {
                          uid
                          data {
                            image {
                              gatsbyImageData(aspectRatio: 1.5)
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
 result2: allPrismicCollection {
    nodes {
      data {
          collection {
          text
        }
        slides {
          slide {
            document {
              ... on PrismicSlide {
                id
                data {
                  blogs {
                    blog {
                      document {
                        ... on PrismicBlog {
                          id
                          data {
                            tags {
                              tag
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      
      }
    }
  }
```

The result of each specific query, instead of being inside `props.data.allPrismicCollection` will be inside of `props.data.result1` and `props.data.result2` respectively.

Comment: I also fixed this by using `useStaticQuery` directly in my component !